# find the word before specific string in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have string

```
exp='"\"OLS\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"QUANTITY\"  <50 and  \"OLS\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_NAME\"  = 'Kingston''
```

How can I find word before string `\"OLS\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_NAME\"  = 'Kingston'` that is **and** in my case

result should be **and**

Comment: Should the end be `\'Kingston\'`?

Comment: yes it should be this entire string `\"OLS\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_NAME\"  = 'Kingston'`

Comment: Could you please post any code that you have attempted so far to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way (after fixing your string literal):

```
import re

exp='"OLS"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"  <50 and  "OLS"."PRODUCTS"."PRODUCT_NAME"  = \'Kingston\''

search_for = '"OLS"."PRODUCTS"."PRODUCT_NAME"'

m = re.search(r'(\w+)\s+' + search_for, exp)
print(m.group(1))
```

Result:

```
and
```

Note that there's no reason to escape the double quote characters in your string, since you're defining the string with single quotes. For the same reason, you do have to escape the single quotes around `Kingston`.

Comment: in place of `"OLS"."PRODUCTS"."PRODUCT_NAME"` i want to pass a variable that makes it dynamic.how can i do this?

Comment: Basically, just do it.  I'll add that to my answer...

Comment: tried with `exp='"OLS"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"  in ('CPU') and "OLS"."ORDERS"."STATUS"  in ('Shipped','Canceled') and "OLS"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"  in ('RAM') or "OLS"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"  in ('Storage')'` `search_for='"OLS"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"  in ('RAM')'`..Its returning None

Comment: returns None for this as well `search_for='"OLS"."PRODUCTS"."PRODUCT_NAME"  = \'Kingston\''  exp= '"OLS"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY"  <50 and  "OLS"."PRODUCTS"."PRODUCT_NAME"  = \'Kingston\''`

Comment: Second one works for me when I try it.  The first one doesn't work because '(' and ')' are special in regular expressions, which is what we're creating here.  We have to escape those.  Add this line just before you use `search_for` to escape the parentheses in it:  `search_for = search_for.replace('(', '\(').replace(')', '\)')`. That will let the first new example work.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
key = "\"OLS\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_NAME\"  = 'Kingston'"
exp[:exp.index(key)].split()[-1]
```